# LinearLayout super(context) exception on android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, superclass, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have a NullPointerException on **super(context)** line in the constructor of a custom view class which extend LinearLayout. The problem do not appear by testing with android 4.1.2 virtual device.

```
public class customView extends LinearLayout {
  private NavigationBar navigationBar;
  private Activity activity;
  public customView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    activity = (Activity) context;
    navigationBar = new NavigationBar(context);
    LayoutParams Params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    setLayoutParams(Params);
    setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    this.addView(navigationBar);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout
{

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        Init(context);
    }

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        Init(context);
    }

    private void Init(Context context)
    {
        activity = (Activity) context;

        navigationBar = new NavigationBar(context);
        LayoutParams Params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,         LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        setLayoutParams(Params);
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        this.addView(navigationBar);
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the error. I have incorrectly overridden the invalidate() method in my custom LinearLayout class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it with:

```
public class customView extends LinearLayout {
      private NavigationBar navigationBar;

      public customView(Context context)
   {
         super(context);


     navigationBar = new NavigationBar(context);
     LayoutParams Params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,   LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
     setLayoutParams(Params);
     setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

     this.addView(navigationBar);
}
```

Comment: No the implicit super constructor LinearLayout() must be defined.